# Finding the value of n if $2^{200}-2^{192}31 +2^n$ is perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Problem :

Finding the value of n if $2^{200}-2^{192}31 +2^n$ is perfect square

Solution :

$2^{200}-2^{192}31 +2^n = 2^{192}(2^8-31)+2^n$

= $2^{192}(256-31)+2^n = 2^{192}(225)+2^n$

$\therefore$ for some $m \in N$

$2^n = m^2-2^{192}225$
=$m^2-(2^{96}.15)^2$

=$(m-2^{96}.15)(m+2^{96}.15)$

$m = 2^{96}.15 = 2^{\alpha}$ and $m+2^{96}.15 = 2^{\alpha +\beta}$  ( I am unable to understand this point, please explain this point .. thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $xy$ is a power of $2$, then $x$ is a power of $2$, and so is $y$ (by the Unique Factorization Theorem). So what I think you meant to write would be $m-2^{96}\cdot15=2^{\alpha}$. Then $m+2^{96}\cdot15$ is a bigger power of $2$, so it's $2^{\alpha+\beta}$.

Comment: thanks a lot  I got the answer.... it was great...